# How to continually run QProcess while running my QML program?

Tags: qt, qml

The problem I have in my code is, once the QML engine uplouded the QProcess stop!! Is it possible to let QProcess run while the QMLis already in operation!

the idea is: I want the user to be able to interact with only one specific mouse and one keyboard and to continually check this condition!
Can some one check what is the problem here?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    bool scanForDevices=0;
    USBdeviceID *usbdeviceid =new USBdeviceID();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("USBdeviceID", usbdeviceid);
    QProcess OProcess;
    QString Command;    //Contains the command to be execute
    Command = "lsusb";

    while (1)
    {
        OProcess.start(Command,QIODevice::ReadOnly); //Starts execution of command
        OProcess.waitForFinished();                       //Waits for execution to complete

        QString StdOut      =   OProcess.readAllStandardOutput();  //Reads standard output
        QString StdError    =   OProcess.readAllStandardError();   //Reads standard error

        cout<<"\n Printing the standard output..........\n";
        cout<<endl<<StdOut.toStdString();
        bool mouse1 = StdOut.contains("ID 046d:c03e");                                                   
        bool keyBoard1 = StdOut.contains("ID 413c:1003"); 

        if (mouse1 ==1 && keyBoard1==1)
        {


            // start main program
            // revoke A signal to tell QML the correct devices are connected
            usbdeviceid->setMouse1Detected(1);
            usbdeviceid->setkeyBoard1Detected(1);
            engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
            if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
                return -1;
            return app.exec();

              }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have doubts about your logic, let's say that scanForDevices is 1 but in an instant after mouse1 and keyBoard1 are not 1, what should happen in that case?

Comment: yes you are correct, I will adjust that

Comment: I think now it is better

Comment: the idea is: I want the user to be able to interact with only one specific mouse and one keyboard

Comment: You still do not answer my question, what should happen with the window if mouse1 or keyBoard1 are not 1? Should it be closed or what?

Comment: No just wait till this condition come!

Comment: I mean, just check that condition at the beginning, and if it complies then launch the window, then nothing else is verified anymore. Am I correct? Although you do not do it in the most elegant way but that is what your code does.

Comment: that why I don't like my code, I wanted to make it more clean! but don't know how!

Comment: That you should indicate in your question since your question is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to create infinite loops in Qt, instead the most elegant thing is to use the signals.

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class LSUSB: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    LSUSB(const QStringList & ids, QObject *parent=nullptr): QObject(parent), status(false), ids(ids)
    {
        QString command = "lsusb";
        connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &LSUSB::onReadyReadStandardOutput);
        connect(&process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, &LSUSB::onFinished);
        process.setProgram(command);
        process.start();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void isLoaded();
private Q_SLOTS:
    void onReadyReadStandardOutput(){
        QString stdout = process.readAllStandardOutput();
        status = true;
        for(const QString & id: ids){
            status &= stdout.contains(id);
        }
        if(status){
            process.kill();
            Q_EMIT isLoaded();
        }
    }
    void onFinished(){
        if(!status)
            process.start();
    }
private:
    QProcess process;
    bool status;
    QStringList ids;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    LSUSB lsusb({"ID 046d:c03e", "ID 413c:1003"});
    USBdeviceID usbdeviceid;
    QObject::connect(&lsusb, &LSUSB::isLoaded, [&engine, &usbdeviceid](){
        usbdeviceid.setMouse1Detected(1);
        usbdeviceid.setkeyBoard1Detected(1);
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    });
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: In case of the ID is wrong! How can I update this conditions in your code?
  usbdeviceid.setMouse1Detected(0);
  usbdeviceid.setkeyBoard1Detected(0);